# Windows 11 Edge cannot open PDFs that have spaces in filename

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

Windows 11 Edge opens PDF by default, but it seems like it can't handle filenames that have spaces. e.g. `Invoice AAA.pdf` will result in opening 2 tabs, `Invoice` and `AAA.pdf`, both of which don't exist.

Are there any solutions for such files to properly open in Edge?

I prefer to remain using Edge (instead of Chrome) because it gives it a distinctively different icon which makes looking for PDFs easier.

### UPDATE

- Video showing what happens for avoidance of doubt https://imgur.com/a/37XcCi8

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce this on the current version of Edge on Windows 10 22H2

Comment: And no issue opening PDF with spaces in the Filename on Windows 11 either.

Comment: That would seem likely only if using a Linux file server, or WSL on Win 11, since I've rarely seen Windows filenames space sensitive, though Linux is more so. Another possibility is that the character *appearing* as a space is actually another, e.g., ASCII 160, NBS. Test by substituting a known real space in the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the culprit to be MSEdgeRedirector and filed a report which was fixed very quickly https://github.com/rcmaehl/MSEdgeRedirect/issues/390

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this occurring with some applications when the registry has been manually modified to change the open with behavior of a file type and application. Whether you've manually manipulated your registry or not, try this to reset the behavior:

**Re-Tell Windows To Open PDFs Using Edge**
The simplest way to do this is:

1. Right-click on and PDF file on your computer.
2. Choose "Open With"
3. Choose "Choose another app"
4. Select Microsoft Edge from this list
5. Mark the box "Always open with this application"
6. Click OK
7. Confirm whether the behavior is resolved

If it is not, then there is probably an issue with your OS and you should probably perform basic Windows repair methods to try to correct that.

You can also try setting a different program to be your PDF handler, then setting it back to Edge just to see if that shakes loose whatever bugs were in the handler settings.

Comment: I followed your steps but no joy. However, it did remind me that I have MSEdgeRedirect installed and that was the cause of it. Removing MSEdgeRedirect made the problem go away.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer and then accept it, in order to help others who may experience the same issue going forward.